# SQL check DATE between two times for any day

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have a transaction table, and my problem is keeping track of the `transactionDateTime` column. Using SQL, I can't seem to get the `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` to format so that any inserted data has to be between 8am and 10pm on any given day:

```
    CREATE TABLE Transaction_T
      (transactionID          NUMBER(8,0)              ,
       employeeID             NUMBER(10,0)      NOT NULL,
       customerID             NUMBER(6,0)       NOT NULL,
       transactionDate        VARCHAR2(9)       NOT NULL,
       transactionPayment     VARCHAR2(10) check(transactionPayment IN('cash','credit','debit','ebt')),
       transactionType        VARCHAR2(10) check(transactionType IN('void','return','sale')),
       transactionDateTime    TIMESTAMP check(transactionDateTime < '% 22:00:00' AND transactionDateTime > '% 08:00:00') NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT TransactionPK PRIMARY KEY (transactionID),
CONSTRAINT TransactionFK1 FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES Employee_T(employeeID),
CONSTRAINT TranscationFK2 FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customer_T(customerID));
```

The table above is created, but when trying to insert a correct `Date(Time)`, I receive format errors regarding hours between 1 and 12 or not a valid month when the time is below 12. I've used Oracle documentation format and still no luck:

```
INSERT INTO 
transaction_T(transactionID, employeeID, customerID, transactionDate, transactionPayment, transactionType, transactionDateTime) 
VALUES(00000001, 0001, 000004, '04-APR-13','ebt','sale','04-APR-13 13:25:10');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `%` in your check constraint won't work here. Try this instead:

```
CHECK (
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM transactionDateTime) < 22 AND
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM transactionDateTime) >= 8)
```

Comment: Will this work with timestamp or date in sql? Also, do you have any feedback on my insertion format for timestamp?

Comment: `EXTRACT` will work on `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` values. The documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm). The best insertion format is the ANSI literal: `TIMESTAMP '2013-02-27 12:34:56.789'`, or if you're dealing with time zones then it's `TIMESTAMP '1997-01-31 09:26:56.66 +02:00'`. There's more about the literals [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) - it's a huge page covering all sorts of literals, with timestamps coming about two-thirds of the way down the page.

Comment: I'm still getting "not a valid month" when I try to insert this format: '2013-04-04 13:25:10.789'

Comment: You need to prefix it with `TIMESTAMP`, so instead of `'2013-04-04 13:25:10.789'` do it exactly like this: `TIMESTAMP '2013-04-04 13:25:10.789'`.

Comment: Also, is there a data type equivalent to just Time?

Comment: Nope, nothing for just "time of day". There is an `INTERVAL` type that stores a time span, either as years/months or days/seconds. But if you need "time of day" you should use a `TIMESTAMP` (or a `DATE`) and extract the time of day as needed. Here's one reason: if you have just "time" then 8AM is always less than 9AM. In reality that's not always true because 8AM on 4/12/2013 is *greater than* 9AM on 4/11/2013.

Comment: Great answer, so I went with time stamp. I'll just extract certain parts from queries when needed. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can express your check constraint like this:

```
check(transactionDateTime between trunc(transactionDateTime) + 8/24 and trunc(transactionDateTime) + 22/24))
```